# Excel vba: copying specific data from multiple excel files selected by user

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA, so please do not judge so harshly :)

I'm trying to write macro which will allow to copy specified information from multiple files chosen by user and paste it to the one desired sheet. My code is below, no errors appears, but actually it doesn't work - no data is copied to desired workbook. Could anyone explain where is mistake?

```
Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
'IMPORTANT!
fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
 
'Optional FileDialog properties
fDialog.Title = "Select a file"
fDialog.InitialFileName = "C:\"
'Optional: Add filters
fDialog.Filters.Clear
fDialog.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xlsx"
fDialog.Filters.Add "All files", "*.*"
 
'Show the dialog. -1 means success!
If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
  For Each it In fDialog.SelectedItems
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim src As Workbook
    
    ' OPEN THE SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK IN "READ ONLY MODE".
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(it, True, True)
    
        ' COPY DATA FROM SOURCE (CLOSE WORKGROUP) TO THE DESTINATION WORKBOOK.
        Dim iCnt As Integer
        Dim n As Range
        Dim iTotalRows As Integer
        
        iTotalRows = 100
        
        For iCnt = 2 To iTotalRows
            
            Set n = src.Worksheets(1).Range("A10:A47").Find(ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 2))
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "January 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 4).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "February 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 5).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 5).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "March 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 6).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 6).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "April 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 7).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 7).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "May 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 8).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 8).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "June 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 9).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 9).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "July 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 10).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 10).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "August 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 11).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 11).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "September 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 12).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 12).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "October 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 13).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 13).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "November 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 14).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 14).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                
                If src.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, 5) = "December 2022" Then
                    i=n.Row+1
                    Do While src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = ""
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 15).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(iCnt, 16).Value & src.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value & "; "
                        i = i + 1
                    Loop
                End If
          
        Next iCnt
    
    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    src.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set src = Nothing
    
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
  Next it
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to comment the `on error goto`line out, to check if an error is triggered. Be carefull to use `ActiveSheet`, by opening a new workbook a sheet of this new workbook is active.

Comment: Error is not triggered, it seems that code stops on DO WHILE loop, cause selected file opens and thats all. Thanks for the valuable advice.

Comment: I have changed ActiveSheet to wkbD.Sheets(1).cells() but still no effect. File opens, bu nothing happens after - seems that error occurs in Do While Loop, or earlier. Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Is the do-while loop executed? What is the purpose of this loop? Since `n` is fixed and `i` is not used in the loop, the loop makes no sense.

Comment: @Shrotter Good point, I have edited code and completed i definition. But still not working :(

Comment: @Shrotter Sometimes appears error: 'Run time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set' on line where i is defined `i=n.Row + 1`

Comment: You have to check if something was found (`If Not n Is Nothing Then`). Does your do-while loop multiple times? If first `.Cells(i, 1)` is not empty, the loop never processed

Comment: The Do-While loop is correct, it is made due to source file structure. `If Not n Is Nothing Then` helped, the desired effect was achieved. Thank you for your time and tips.